# object detection inference for high resolution images is taking huge time on cpu

Tags: pytorch, fast-ai

I have trained the ML model on pascal dataset with the image size of 224 but when inferencing on new images (some are of high resolution and some are of slightly higher resolution than the pascal images), I get the error in `pil2tensor()`

```
@app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
async def analyze(request):
    data = await request.form()
    img_bytes = await (data['file'].read())
    img = open_image(BytesIO(img_bytes))

    t_img= PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(img_bytes)).convert('RGB')
    t_img = pil2tensor(t_img, np.float32)
    t_img = t_img.div_(255)
    with torch.no_grad():
        # test_output = learn.model.eval()(t_img.unsqueeze_(0).cuda())
        test_output = learn.model.eval()(t_img.unsqueeze_(0))
```

for small image sizes (like some low-resolution images from google), ML model is correctly able to make inference within seconds but for even slightly higher resolution images, it's taking around 20-40 minutes !!!

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue, here is the correct code:

```
@app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
async def analyze(request):
    data = await request.form()
    img_bytes = await (data['file'].read())
    img = open_image(BytesIO(img_bytes))
    localtime = _utc_to_local(datetime.utcnow())

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    media_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "media")
    media_path_original = os.path.join(media_path, "original")
    media_path_processed = os.path.join(media_path, "processed")

    img_path = os.path.join(media_path_original, localtime+".jpg")
    img.save(img_path)
    verify_image(Path(img_path), idx=0, delete=False, max_size=600, dest=Path(media_path_processed))
    processed_img_path = os.path.join(media_path_processed, localtime+".jpg")
    processed_img = open_image(processed_img_path) if os.path.exists(processed_img_path) else img
    processed_img.refresh()
    with torch.no_grad():
        test_output = learn.model.eval()(processed_img.data.unsqueeze(0))
        predictions = show_preds(processed_img, test_output, 0, detect_thresh=0.4, classes=t_classes)
    img_height, img_width = processed_img.size
    return JSONResponse({'predictions': predictions, 'img_height': img_height, 'img_width': img_width})
```